# Python script to upload file with a presigned URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

Snippet of my code below, basically I go through a specified directory and for each file in that directory get a presigned URL to upload it to S3.  Am I on the right track to think I can use curl in the for loop to upload each file with the presigned URL or do I need to approach it a different way.

---

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': bucket,
        'Key': name
        }
    )
    print(url)
```